# Split and combine two different strings

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a string and below is the thing which i am trying to achieve:

```
String first = "Previous.value1 | Previous.value2";
String second = "New.value1| New.value2";
```

I am trying to create final string like this:

```
string final ="generate Previous.value1 cross New.value1 ? Previous.value1 cross New.value2";
```

**But problem** is when i will have mismatch like below:

```
String first = "Previous.value1 | Previous.value2";
String second = "New.value1";
```

Then i want to have like this because i dont have matching value for **Previous.Value2** in **second variable**:

```
string final ="generate Previous.value1 cross New.value1";
```

So far i am successfully in generating final string when i have same count of value in both the string.

```
string final = "generate";
if (first.Split('|').Count() - second.Split('|').Count() == 0)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in first.Split('|').Count())
    {
        if (i == 0)
            final = final + item + " cross " + second.Split('|')[i];
        else
            final = final +  " ? " + item + " cross " + second.Split('|')[index];
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: if(second.Contains("|")){ //do something}

Comment: @TimSchmelter:i have updated my question with the changes.Sorry

Comment: @Cubi :See my updated question where i have highlighted the problem section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this LINQ query (using [the `Zip` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.140).aspx)):

```
var zippedQry = first.Split('|').Zip(second.Split('|'),
    (f, s) => f.Trim() + " cross " + s.Trim());
string final = "generate " + String.Join(" ? ", zippedQry.ToArray());
```

Comment: Can you please explain me your code most importantly zip function to learn this new zip function and its usage.please

Comment: For details about the Zip function, click on the link I have provided in my post. It basically takes two separate lists (in your case the split strings) and combines them into one list with a selector (in your case creating the text with "cross"). In the second line, the combined list is joined to one string.

Comment: But how does this function behaves in this scenario : String first = "Previous.value1 | Previous.value2";
String second = "New.value1";.Can you explain me with respect to this input??

Comment: This is what the MSDN page I linked says: " If the sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method merges sequences until it reaches the end of one of them. For example, if one sequence has three elements and the other one has four, the result sequence will have only three elements." So the part after the `|` in your example will be ignored and you will get the desired result. I recommend you try this in the debugger.

Comment: Sir you know I always know 1 thing that you guys always have better solution than what I do.see the way I have done and the way you have done in just 2 lines.huge difference. How you guys always have a better way to do the things

Comment: Glad to help. As a general takeaway: you can do pretty powerful stuff with lists with LINQ. Anyway, if you'd met me you'd know I'm not a sir. ;-)

Comment: Can you help me with this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889240/creating-function-syntax-by-manipulating-string

Comment: Check my mybirthname's answer there. This is what you are looking for.

Comment: See my updated question with the cases of input and expected output

Answer (score 1):

To remain in the style that you use, I would suggest to first split both strings

```
String first = "Previous.value1 | Previous.value2";
String second = "New.value1 | New.value2";
string final = "generate ";

string[] first_values = first.Split('|');
string[] second_values = second.Split('|');
```

Then you can just orient yourself on the shortest array. If you have in the `second_values` not enough corresponding values for the `first_values` you collect only the corresponding ones. Using a normal for-loop:

```
// run until the length of the shortest one
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(first_values.Length, second_values.Length); i++)
{
    // bild the normal cross-version for the first position
    string sentence = first_values[i] + " cross " + second_values[i];
    // if on first position use normal version otherwise put a ? infront of it
    final += i == 0 ? sentence : " ? " + sentence;
}
```

This loop should handle also string like this:

```
String first = "Previous.value1 | Previous.value2 | Previous.value3 | Previous.value4";
String second = "New.value1 | New.value2 | New.value3";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for your kind help :)