# Creating function syntax by manipulating string

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to create dynamic syntax function and function syntax is like below:

```
MyFunction( arg1,arg2,ar3.....);
```

I have string like this:

```
str = Previousvalue.Value1,Previousvalue.Value2
```

Now I would like to create syntax like this in final variable :

```
String final = MyFunction(Previousvalue.Value1,',',Previousvalue.Value2);

str = Previousvalue.Value1,Previousvalue.Value2,Previousvalue.Value3;
String final = MyFunction(Previousvalue.Value1,',',Previousvalue.Value2,',',Previousvalue.Value3);
```

This is how I am trying to achieve with `string.join` (without using loop) but not getting how to do it and this seems like impossible to do without using loop:

```
final =  string.Join("MyFunction(", str.Split(','));
```

**Case 1:**

```
Input : string str =Previousvalue.Value1,Previousvalue.Value2
```

**Output:**

```
string final=MyFunction(Previousvalue.Value1,',',Previousvalue.Value2,',',Previousvalue.Value3);
```

**Case 2 :**

```
Input : str = Previousvalue.Value1,Previousvalue.Value2,Previousvalue.Value3;
```

**output**:

```
String final = MyFunction(Previousvalue.Value1,',',Previousvalue.Value2,',',Previousvalue.Value3);
```

**Case 3:**

```
string input = " Previousvalue.Value1";
```

**Output:**

```
String final = Previousvalue.Value1; //No function
```

Comment: Sorry, not clear. What exactly is the string and what is the desired result with this sample string?

Comment: @TimSchmelter :I have updated question to show input and output

Comment: Well, you have still provided an output `"String final = MyFunction(..."`, is the `String final` part of the string or is it a variable declaration? If the latter, why haven't you wrapped the `MyFunction`-part in quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to generate a **string** like this:

```
"MyFunction(Previousvalue.Value1,',',Previousvalue.Value2);"
 ^..........^...................^....^...................^.
 prefix     arg1                sep  arg2                suffix
```

or in other words

```
prefix = "MyFunction(";
separator = ",',',";
suffix = ");"
```

which can be achieved by moving the `prefix` and `suffix` out of the `string.Join` and using the above `separator` value:

```
string final = "MyFunction(" + string.Join(",',',", str.Split(',')) + ");";
```

Also instead of `Split` / `Join` you could simply use `string.Replace`:

```
string final = "MyFunction(" + str.Replace(",", ",',',") + ");";
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the problem you want to call the `MyFunction` method with *n* string parameters, but also with `string[]`. You can do it like this:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "Test1,Test2,Test3";

        string test1 = MyFunction("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");
        string test2 = MyFunction(str.Split(','));
    }

    public static string MyFunction(params string[] parameters)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var item in parameters)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(item);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Please see my updated question with 2 cases which shows input and output

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
public string MyJoin(params string[] vars)
{
    return "MyFunction(" + string.Join(",", vars) + ");";
}
```

Comment: Sorry but using your answer i am getting comma in between 2 variable like in my output